# How to get total no of rows affected by DML Statements in a DBMS Session of PLSQL block(Without using SQL%ROWCOUNT)?

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g

I have a situation where I have multiple DML statements in a PLSQL Block, I wanted to know no of rows
affected in a current session(Rows affected by DML Statements).

There can be 50-100 DML statements on different tables, I don't want to use SQL%ROWCOUNT again and again after every single DML statement, do we have any option where I can get an aggregate amount of rows affected in a particular session?

Table Structure :

```
create table client_A (
  val_cli integer
 ,status varchar2(10)
);

create table client_B (
  val_cli integer
 ,status varchar2(10)
);

create table client_C (
  val_cli integer
 ,status varchar2(10)
);
```

Dummy Values :

```
insert into client_A
select 1, 'void' from dual
union all
select 4, 'void' from dual
union all
select 1, 'void' from dual
union all
select 6, 'void' from dual
union all
select 10, 'void' from dual;

insert into client_B
select 1, 'void' from dual
union all
select 4, 'void' from dual
union all
select 1, 'void' from dual
union all
select 6, 'void' from dual
union all
select 10, 'void' from dual;


insert into client_C
select 1, 'void' from dual
union all
select 4, 'void' from dual
union all
select 1, 'void' from dual
union all
select 6, 'void' from dual
union all
select 10, 'void' from dual;

commit;
```

BLOCK :

```
begin
update client_A set status = 'ok' where val_cli = 1;
update client_B set status = 'ok' where val_cli = 1; 
update client_C set status = 'ok' where val_cli = 1;
-- More DML Statements
commit;
end;
```

PS: There May Exist 50 -100 DML Statement so I want to avoid usage of ROWCOUNT and I am looking for any generic approach to get the number of rows affected in a given session or block.

Comment: "do we have any option where I can get an aggregate amount of rows affected in a particular session?" Yes, use `SQL%ROWCOUNT`. Why do you not want to use that?

Comment: @MT0, I actually used it earlier but now the situation is that I can have no of DML statement and these will be dynamic so I don't want to add SQL%ROWCOUNT after every query, instead I was looking for any generic approach or some api which can tell no of affected rows by DML in a particular session.

Comment: I see a usage of ROWCOUNT in question mentioned as the reference(Duplicate), I have explicitly mentioned the approach I am looking for.

Comment: There is no other way